# Temporarily storing data in array while wiping source

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, core-data

We are using Core Data to store information locally on our iOS App. When we update information remotely, the app deletes the local data in the core data, and replaces it with the new. This is the way we designed it, and it works perfectly. However, now we need some of the data to stay. We have included some user-editable fields, and need one of the entities to have some of the old information. I tried to make a fetch-request for the entire entity, store them in an array, and delete the entity, then update to new data, and then push over the old data from the stored array. However, all the data on the array gets wiped when I clear out the Core Data.. We have tried with NSArray, NSMutableArray, and initializing with initWithArray:a copyItems:YES.. How can we store information in an array and then delete the source?

Comment: Remove all except what need to stay

Comment: @NeverBe That does not solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data from your array using NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
```

Pull the Data using

```
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
```

Comment: This is really an abuse of `NSUserDefaults`.